# CopyWebpackPlugin from array

Tags: webpack

Is there a way set file paths by an array in **CopyWebpackPlugin** "from". I mean something like this

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: [
                    './dir1/file1',
                    './dir2/file2',
                ],
                to: 'assets/'
            }
        ])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use an array, but globs from [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch)
So something like this will work.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: './+(dir1|dir2)/+(file1|file2)', to: 'assets/' },
])
```

Or you just define multiple from to

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: './dir1/file1', to: 'assets/' },
    { from: './dir2/file2', to: 'assets/' },
])
```

Comment: I have a scenario where there's always the same From directory but the To directory can be either one, two or three directories.  It seems there is no way to make this optional. Or as in your example above. Imagine if you sometimes only have dir1. Sometimes you have also dir2. But not always. Could that be handled without having an If {} else , since that is a bit bulky; two CopyWebpackPlugins just to accomodate for the fact that number of direcrtories varies. Thanks